# web.xml default file in directory (for jetty, or tomcat)?

Tags: tomcat, jetty, web.xml

I have a directory called ./welcome/ and ./welcome/ has a file called ./index.jsp.

I know how to tell jetty or tomcat how to start at ./wecome/index.jsp. But, I also have lots of other directories with an ./index.jsp like --- ./blogs/, ./whatever/, etc.

Without using servlets, is there a way to tell jetty or tomcat, "hey, whenever you get a request for a directory, see if there is an ./index.jsp -- and display it to the user."

Like if I access ./blogs/ I dont want to see a 404 not found. I want to see the contents of  ./blogs/index.jsp, but I dont want my users to be redirected to ./blogs/index.jsp -- I want their browsers to still only display ./blogs/

I know apache has such as feature. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> "hey, whenever you get a request for a directory, see if there is an ./index.jsp -- and display it to the user."

That's exactly what `welcome-file-list` is supposed to do.

Simply add the following to web.xml. In this case, first the container will try `index.html` and if it does not exist, then it will try `index.jsp`.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I've tested this on Tomcat 5.5, and it works correctly.

Unfortunately, it's really hard to find the official reference for web.xml. So [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1026980) is the documentation for Oracle weblogic instead; I think it can be trusted...

Comment: oh! haha, this was such a silly question come to think about it. I thought I had it all correct, by my welcome-file-list was set to ./welcome/index.jsp -- no wonder, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

refer above:

> first the container will try index.html and if it does not exist, then it will try index.jsp.

my app alway use index.html, when there are both index.jsp, index.html, regardless of the config sequense.