# how to access http://www.myjsfapp.com/index.html in a jsf app?

Tags: java, jsf, url

In the browser url bar the welcome page of my jsf app appears like:

```
http://www.myjsfapp.com/
```

I'd need to access it as:

```
http://www.myjsfapp.com/index.html
```

for the purpose of actually passing parameters:

```
http://www.myjsfapp.com/index.html?param=value
```

But `http://www.myjsfapp.com/index.html` gives me a 404.

What is it that I am missing?

Note: my web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Did you configure your server to serve something useful there? (myjsfapp.com is not automatically the same as www.myjsfapp.com)

Comment: I test it in localhost at the moment.

Comment: and I edited the question to reflect your comment

Comment: See here for what i mean http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-redirect-domaincom-to-wwwdomaincom/

Comment: Just map the faces servlet on `*.xhtml`. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885874/jsf-welcome-file-not-recognized/7889247#7889247 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237416/welcome-file-in-web-xml-with-spring-not-working/10255837#10255837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no index.html file in your project. Your welcome page is index.xhtml. take attention between xhtml and html.

Furthermore, if you have a servlet mapping for `/faces/*` in your web.xml. index.xhtml should be accessed as `http://myjsfapp.com/faces/index.xhtml?param=value`. It is possible to access  `http://myjsfapp.com/ index.xhtml?param=value`, but this URL will not have JSF capabilities.

Once you add a servlet mapping like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The request which includes `/faces/*` patterns in the URL will be controlled by mapped servlet. It is `Faces Servlet` and it will be controlled by `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` class. This servlet mapping give your requests JSF capability. Other URLs not having /faces/* will not run inside `Faces Servlet` meaning there is no JSF capability.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the servlet mapping to */faces/*. Thanks and sorry for such a basic mistake!

Comment: The URL pattern in your answer has a major syntax error.

Comment: @BalusC I think i fixed it by removing `*` in the beginning. Sorry for that.

Comment: I would not recommend using `/faces/*` as URL pattern. Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253366/jsf-tags-are-not-being-rendered/16254010#16254010).